# Adding column with rolling latest prior in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with a list of customers, days, and transaction types.

```
+----------+-----+------+
| Customer | Day | Type |
+----------+-----+------+
| A        |   2 | X11  |
| A        |   4 | X2   |
| A        |   9 | Y4   |
| A        |  11 | X1   |
| B        |   3 | Y4   |
| B        |   7 | X1   |
+----------+-----+------+
```

I'd like to create a column that has "most recent X type" for each customer, like so:

```
+----------+-----+------+-------------+
| Customer | Day | Type | MostRecentX |
+----------+-----+------+-------------+
| A        |   2 | X11  | X11         |
| A        |   4 | X2   | X2          |
| A        |   9 | Y4   | X2          |
| A        |  11 | X1   | X1          |
| B        |   3 | Y4   | -           |
| B        |   7 | X1   | X1          |
+----------+-----+------+-------------+
```

So for the X types it just takes the one from the current row, but for the Y type it takes the type from the most recent X row for that member (and if there isn't one, it gets a blank or something).  I imagine I need a sort of window function but not very familiar with PySpark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve by this taking the [`last`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.last) column that [`startswith`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.startswith) the letter `"X"` over a `Window` that partitions by the `Customer` and orders by the `Day`. Specify the `Window` to start at the beginning of the partition and stop at the current row.

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, last, when

w = Window.partitionBy("Customer").orderBy("Day").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

df = df.withColumn(
    "MostRecentX",
    last(when(col("Type").startswith("X"), col("Type")), ignorenulls=True).over(w)
)
df.show()
#+--------+---+----+-----------+
#|Customer|Day|Type|MostRecentX|
#+--------+---+----+-----------+
#|       A|  2| X11|        X11|
#|       A|  4|  X2|         X2|
#|       A|  9|  Y4|         X2|
#|       A| 11|  X1|         X1|
#|       B|  3|  Y4|       null|
#|       B|  7|  X1|         X1|
#+--------+---+----+-----------+
```

The trick here is to use [`when`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) to return the `Type` column only if it starts with `"X"`. By default, `when` will return `null`. Then we can use `last` with `ignorenulls=True` to get the value for `MostRecentX`.

If you want to replace the `null` with `"-"` as shown in your question, just call `fillna` on the `MostRecentX` column:

```python
df.fillna("-", subset=["MostRecentX"]).show()
#+--------+---+----+-----------+
#|Customer|Day|Type|MostRecentX|
#+--------+---+----+-----------+
#|       A|  2| X11|        X11|
#|       A|  4|  X2|         X2|
#|       A|  9|  Y4|         X2|
#|       A| 11|  X1|         X1|
#|       B|  3|  Y4|          -|
#|       B|  7|  X1|         X1|
#+--------+---+----+-----------+
```